# Tell whether reboot is required after apk upgrade

Tags: package-management, reboot, alpine-linux, apk-tools

How do we know whether we need to reboot after `apk upgrade`? I know that we probably need to reboot after kernel update, but how about system libraries and Busybox (as `init`)?

For Debian we have several ways to do it: [*How can I know if reboot is required after update?* - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/667076/how-can-i-know-if-reboot-is-required-after-update). I’d like to do the same in Alpine Linux.

Answer (score -1):

There is a script [restart-services](https://dev.gentoo.org/%7Emschiff/restart-services/) written for OpenRC in general (it came from Gentoo). The [apk package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/restart-services) is only in the [edge repository](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge), so using it in production is discouraged.

A related project [apk-autoupdate](https://github.com/jirutka/apk-autoupdate) does both `apk upgrade` and restarts. It’s also [in edge](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/apk-autoupdate), and it hasn’t even cut a release, so potentially even less stable.